# How to left join with non-matching sorted data

Tags: r

I have a reference table that displays the prize amount given a finishing percentile is less than or equal to percentile X. I want to join a table that lists actual percentiles to get their prizes, however I don't know how to join or merge by sorted data. Example of what I want:

```
Percentile <- c(.01, .1, .2, .3, .4, .5, 1)
Prize <- c(1000, 100, 25, 6, 3, 2, 0)
refDF <- data.frame(Percentile, Prize)

Person <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
Percentile <- c(.005, .385, .72, .20)
resultDF <- data.frame(Person, Percentile)

MADEUPLEFTJOIN(resultdf, refDF, by = c('Percentile'), sorted = T)

      Person Percentile  Prize
1      1      0.005      1000
2      2      0.385        3
3      3      0.720        0
4      4      0.200       25
```

I'm used to using `dplyr::left_join`, but I went through the documentation and couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you want a ["rolling join,"](https://r-norberg.blogspot.com/2016/06/understanding-datatable-rolling-joins.html) which joins based on the nearest value, rather than an exact match. The `data.table` package does rolling joins and you can join based on the nearest match, the nearest match that's lower than the reference value, or the nearest match that's higher than the reference value. The linked web page has examples.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. I wish there was something like this in `dplyr` but this will work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution using `sqldf` could be as:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("SELECT resultDF.*, refDF.Prize
      FROM resultDF, refDF 
      WHERE  refDF.Percentile = (SELECT min(refDF.Percentile) FROM refDF 
      WHERE refDF.Percentile >= resultDF.Percentile)")

  Person Percentile Prize
1      1      0.005  1000
2      2      0.385     3
3      3      0.720     0
4      4      0.200    25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with baser R:

```
    resultDF$Prize=refDF$Prize[sapply(resultDF$Percentile,function(x) which(x<=refDF$Percentile)[1])]
> resultDF
  Person Percentile Prize
1      1      0.005  1000
2      2      0.385     3
3      3      0.720     0
4      4      0.200    25
```